# Python's file buffer is not flushed inside with block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, buffer

I've got a few big csv files that I open sequentially processing each line and then write the results to a single csv file, my code looks like this(I'm using Python 3.5 on Debian 9 btw):

```
with open("coutput.csv", "w") as outf:
    ## csv_file_names is a list of csv files' paths
    for file_name in csv_file_names:
        with open(file_name) as inf:
            for line in inf:
                ## processing the line's data
                ....
                ## processed data is then stored in processed_line(as an str object)
                outf.write(processed_line)
```

The problem is that it seems that in the last iteration a few of `processed_line` are not being written to the `output.csv`; In another word `output.csv` has a less rows that it supposed to have(about 10 last rows are not written). When I modify my code by adding the `outf.flush` to the end of the first `with block` every thing works just fine(no missing rows).

```
with open("coutput.csv", "w") as outf:
    ## csv_file_names is a list of csv files' paths
    for file_name in csv_file_names:
        with open(file_name) as inf:
            for line in inf:
                ## processing the line's data
                ....
                ## processed data is then stored in processed_line(as an str object)
                outf.write(processed_line)
    ## adding flush solves the problem
    outf.flush()
```

So I was to ask, Should `flush` be used at the end of a (file)context manager all the time?

Comment: Did you try closing the file? Open the `read_file`, then write it's contents to the `write_file` and after writing it, close the `read_file`. This might solve the issue, I am not certain though

Comment: That is odd. The first `open("cout ...` should close the file at the end of the section. So, how do you know that the file has some missing rows?

Comment: I used this pattern, I mean opening a single file for writing and many for reading before in Python but I hadn't had this problem. I counted the rows of the input files and summarized their values and compared it with the number of rows in the output file(after my Python script exited of course).

Answer (score 0):

It's all about leaving the nested part of the `with`.
With the end of the `with` the buffers are cleared and the file gets closed:

```
with open("coutput.csv", "w") as outf:
    outf.write('something')
    outf.write('something more')

    print(1)
    # still in buffer
print(2)
# now its flushed
```

- `print(1)` is inside the `with` >> file is still open and not flushed
- `print(2)` is outside the `with` >> file is now flushed and closed

Comment: You mean at the end of `with block` data would not be flushed automatically?, In that case I guess there maybe a bug somewhere that prevented that. I guess there is a mis-apprehension here, I doubt calling `flush` work the same way as calling a function to write into the stdout.